# How to add a bot to a telegram channel that is not mine

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm writing a telegram bot, which take a post from telegram channel, translate it and send to another channel. How I can add it to not mine channel?
I tried all what I know and I can't find the resolution.
This is a code:

```
from aiogram import executor, types, Dispatcher, Bot 
import logging 
from translate import Translator 
import data 

 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO) 

bot = Bot(token= data.TOKEN) 

dp = Dispatcher(bot) 

 
@dp.channel_post_handler(content_types= ['text', 'photo']) 
async def take_msg(msg: types.Message): 
    try: 
        text = msg.text 
        translator = Translator(to_lang='en', from_lang= 'autodetect') 
        translation = translator.translate(text) 

        if data.idd != str(msg.chat.id): 
            await bot.send_message(chat_id= data.idd, text= translation) 

    except: 
        if data.idd != str(msg.chat.id): 
            await bot.send_photo(data.idd, msg.photo[0].file_id) 


if name == '__main__': 
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates= False)
```

Bot works on the my both channels.

Answer (score 1):

To add a bot to a telegram channel you do not own, you need to be an Admin and  have the permissions to add new users

You also have to be able to modify user permissions so you can change what your bot is allowed to do within the channel

Comment: If I only common user of channel, I can't add bot to that channel?

Comment: No you cannot.  You have to ask an Admin to add the bot for you or your user needs the permission to invite/add other users